# Python 2.7 string argument error

Tags: string, python-2.7

I am writing a program to calculate body mass index, and I've encountered this error. 
When I print b_index after it's defined, it prints as it should.

However if I were to type something like print "Hello %f" %b_index python says the string doesn't have enough arguments, which still doesn't make sense to me because it's a floating point number.

When I remove the b_index variable completely, the program runs fine. Should I use something other than %f?

```
print "Hello! welcome to the BMI calculator!"
print "You can use this calculator to find your BMI or Body Mass Index"
print "Now, tell me about yourself!"
print "What is your name?"

n = raw_input(" >")


print "Ok %s Let's get started." %n
print "What is your weight in kilograms?"

w = float(raw_input(" >"))
print "Ok, now tell me your height in meters?"

h = float(raw_input(" >"))

while w and h == range(1000,):
        print "Try again, enter weight, then height."
        w = float(raw_input(" >"))
        h = float(raw_input(" >"))
if w and h == str:
    print "Numbers only!"


b_index = w / h * 2

if  b_index < 18.5:
    print "Ok %s, your BMI is %s. You are underweight" %n %b_index
elif 18.5 <= b_index < 25.0:
    print "Ok %s, your BMI is %s. You are normal weight" %n %b_index
elif 25.0 <= b_index < 30.0:
    print "Ok %s, your BMI is %s. You are overweight" %n %b_index
elif 30.0 <= b_index:
    print "Ok %s, your BMI is %s. You are obese" %n %b_index
```

And here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "BMI.py", line 28, in <module>
print "Ok %s, your BMI is %s. You are underweight" %n %b_index
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Comment: Where did you get that syntax from? The bit after the `%` for formatting has to be a tuple containing the same number of arguments as you have things to replace in the format string.

Comment: I thought %f stood for floating point... whoops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format string requires a tuple.

```
print "Ok %s, your BMI is %s. You are underweight" %(n,b_index)
```

Comment: Ah, got it, thank you very much. I just assumed %f stood for floating point... haha.

Comment: No worries.  Also check out using `.format()`.  `print "Ok {name}, your BMI is {bmi}. You are underweight".format(name=n,bmi=b_index)`

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
print "Ok %s, your BMI is %s. You are underweight" %n %b_index
```

by:

```
print "Ok %s, your BMI is %s. You are underweight" % (n, b_index)
```

Comment: Ah ok, I see now. I knew there was something with parenthesis I learned before. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ha, it looks like bunch of people have answered this almost at the same time.

Here is the code I ran on my iPython notebook. I just changed your print syntax to what's prefered using a `.format` syntax.

```
print "Hello! welcome to the BMI calculator!"
print "You can use this calculator to find your BMI or Body Mass Index"
print "Now, tell me about yourself!"
print "What is your name?"

n = raw_input(" >")


print "Ok %s Let's get started." %n
print "What is your weight in kilograms?"

w = float(raw_input(" >"))
print "Ok, now tell me your height in meters?"

h = float(raw_input(" >"))

while w and h > range(1000,):
        print "Try again, enter weight, then height."
        w = float(raw_input(" >"))
        h = float(raw_input(" >"))
if w and h == str:
    print "Numbers only!"


b_index = w / h * 2

if  b_index < 18.5:
    print "Ok {}, your BMI is {}. You are underweight".format(n,b_index)
elif 18.5 <= b_index < 25.0:
    print "Ok {}, your BMI is {}. You are normal weight".format(n, b_index)
elif 25.0 <= b_index < 30.0:
    print "Ok {}, your BMI is {}. You are overweight".format(n, b_index)
elif 30.0 <= b_index:
    print "Ok {}, your BMI is {}. You are obese".format(n, b_index)
```

Comment: Ah ok, .format is new to me, I like it. is the % operator falling out of style?

Comment: Yep, I think it is the preferred way now: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html